# Loading an audio file using file dialog and playing it with pygame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

I'm trying to load a file using the tkinter GUI file dialog and then pass this to another function that will play it using pygame (though I'm open to using another package if it's easier), how would I go about doing this? Below is what a code sample that is representative of what I have so far:

```
import tkinter, pygame
from tkinter import *
from pygame import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

def open_masker():
    global fileName
    fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Audio Files", ".wav .ogg"),   ("All Files", "*.*")))
    masker_track = fileName
    if fileName =="": 
        fileName = None 
    else:
        fh = open(fileName, "r")
        fh.close()   


def masker_screen():
    global m_screen
    m_screen = Toplevel(root)
    m_screen.geometry('600x600')
    m_screen.transient(root) 
    m_label = Label(m_screen, text = "Playing New Masker Noise")
    m_label.pack(anchor = CENTER) 
    noise = pygame.mixer.Sound(file = fileName)
    noise.play(0, 5000)
    noise.stop()


b1 = Button(root, text = 'open file',command = open_masker).pack(anchor=CENTER)
b2 = Button(root, text = 'continue', command = masker_screen).pack(anchor = E)

root.mainloop()
```

Which just returns the error that pygame couldn't load the file. Is this because it's being loaded in as a string into the fileName variable? If so, how do I change that and access the actual file?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't import tkinter and then `from tkinter import *`, it does not make much sense, any reason for that?

Comment: You then have also to close the file in the `open_masker`

Comment: Then, your last big problem: why do you play the sound and then you stop it immediately? Of course, you will not hear a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have fixed some problems you had, and this is my complete working solution (see the comments in the code for explanations):

```
import pygame
from tkinter import *  # not advisable to import everything with *
from tkinter import filedialog

pygame.mixer.init() # initializing the mixer

root = Tk()

audio_file_name = ''

def open_masker():
    global audio_file_name
    audio_file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Audio Files", ".wav .ogg"),   ("All Files", "*.*")))

def masker_screen():  
    # we will also use the audio_file_name global variable
    global m_screen, audio_file_name  

    m_screen = Toplevel(root)
    m_screen.geometry('600x600')
    m_screen.transient(root) 
    m_label = Label(m_screen, text = "Playing New Masker Noise")
    m_label.pack(anchor = CENTER)

    if audio_file_name: # play sound if just not an empty string
        noise = pygame.mixer.Sound(audio_file_name)
        noise.play(0, 5000)

b1 = Button(root, text = 'open file',command = open_masker)
# does not make sense to call pack directly 
# and stored the result in a variable, which would be None
b1.pack(anchor=CENTER)

Button(root, text = 'continue', command = masker_screen).pack(anchor = E)

root.mainloop()
```

See [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) for more information on how to use correctly the `mixer` module.

Comment: Thanks! This is just a snippet from the main program I'm writing. It utilizes a bunch of other functions from tkinter. As for the play and then stop immediately, that's important too but only to the function of the main program. Thanks again though, big help!